# SSL Servlet for sensitive User-Data, NonSSL Servlet for everything else

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, ssl, jakarta-ee

I've got different RemoteServiceServlets. One which handles everything which has to do with User-Data. User-Data should be exchanged via a secure SSL connection.

Secondly, there is a normal Servlet which handels everything else which doesn't have to be secure.

Is there a way to declare e.g. in the web.xml file to use SSL for a special servlet and no SSL otherwise?

I'm using Apache + Tomcat. Perhaps, there is a possibility that Apache and the Rewrite-Engine or something can help me with this?

Help would be very appreciated!

All the best,
Thomas

Comment: Just a quick word of caution regarding using `mod_rewrite` to "convert" your HTTP requests into HTTPS requests: the initial HTTP request will still be made in clear by the client, before the server sends the redirection to the HTTPS URL.

Answer (score 4):

check out this link:

http://techtracer.com/2007/09/12/setting-up-ssl-on-tomcat-in-3-easy-steps/

you can define the paths which you like to to be accessed by ssl by defining these in the web.xml file (as you guessed)

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>securedapp</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
      <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
      </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

You only have to adjust the url-pattern.

Greets

Answer (score 0):

You'll hit the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) if you try to use both SSL and "in the clear" requests in your app (whether the scripts are loaded from a secure or unsecure origin; so the `<add-linker>` suggested by Peter won't be of any help here).

Recent browsers (exception Internet Explorer, of course, or at least not without a few tricks, which in GWT are unfortunately [more like hacks](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5715)), with [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors), will allow you to do this, but because you'll mix secured and unsecured calls will display a nasty "unsecure" badge next to the URL.

If you need SSL for some requests, then you should use SSL **everywhere**. There are nowadays no reason to mix secured and unsecured requests in the same app.

Comment: What solution do you propose if you use GWT Google Maps in your app to get rid of the 'unsecure' warnings? Paying for a premium account is no option.

Comment: Either live with the warning (but only because of Maps API v2), as many (most?) people don't (yet) pay attention to it (except in IE of course); or (inclusive!) contribute to [GALGWT's Maps API v3 support](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/source/browse/changes/vinays/gwt-google-maps-v3/); or [use JSNI](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/MapsFAQ#How_can_I_use_GWT_with_Maps_API_3.0?) or a [non-official project](http://code.google.com/query/#q=gwt%20maps%20v3).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JSONP](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/jsonp/client/JsonpRequestBuilder.html) to bypass the SOP. You could create requests for user related data that are secured with SSL.